# Process Monitor Unknown Module

Tags: windows, debugging, process, operating-system

In [process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) utility I'm trying to monitor a create process call. When the call happens and I see stack of the CreateProcess Call and I see some module entries as "Unknown".

[image]

After the call finished, when I attach the process with debugger and try to dump the address using u , I see the memory is not accessible.

[image]

I want to know, if there is any way I can find out the module / function name ?

Comment: Did you get anywhere w/ this? I am also seeing <unknown> in my stack traces. Thank you.

Comment: No. Not yet. I've seen sometimes JIT code give out put like this in Porcess Monitor. But in this case it was not JIT code.

Comment: OK, thank you for your response.

Comment: Hi, we are experiencing a similar problem. However in our case our application tries to write to a file in %tmp% folder , at 99% the app hangs and the only way to be able to kill the app is restart Windows, during this time other apps and windows are ok. in process monitor stack window we see a unknown module present. A strange issue is there are some machines where this feature works fine meaning we don't see the hang issue. We have exhausted several other avenues like looking at windows patches/programs installed , windows event viewer logs so far no luck yet. Any ideas appreciated. Thanks.